# Run url ervery 2 minutes using cron jobs in php ubuntu not working

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron

i want to execute a url for every 2 min in php so i followed the steps

```
1) crontab -e 
2)select nano editer
3)insert the line
```

* * * * * /usr/bin/GET http://www.gmail.com/sendMail

After saving the file I got the response

```
no crontab for root - using an empty one
crontab: installing new crontab
```

Is there any wrong with the command.
Can any one help me out.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that. Try `man cron` for info on how cron works.

Answer (score 0):

you can use curl for hitting URL

follow following steps :

```
crontab -e
```

add following line to the file

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/curl www.google.com
```

to know more about curl you can do

```
man curl
```